# React Highcharts: How to display tooltip value to specific div outside of the chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I couldn't search similar questions.

Is there any way to display Highcharts tooltip value(`this.x`, `this.y`) to another specific `<div>` which is outside of the chart?

Here's an example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/9fwt8

I think it's using [tooltip.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter), but I don't know the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the value from the tooltip by changing the state.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-taqxqh?file=index.js

Comment: Thank you! Your code was very helpful. I wonder if there is a way to designate a div in which tooltip value will be displayed.